# Linking view with controller in order to call a function from the model class

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've been trying to do something that should be very simple but somehow isn't in this particular project I've been working on.

It's a simple CodeIgniter 3 project. I'm just trying to make a very simple page that will let me select a `.txt` file containing a multitude of coordinates, and add it into my database.

The code for the model is already done for that purpose. I'm trying to link my view so that when I click on the submit button after choosing the `.txt` file, it will call a specific function in my controller that will in turn call my model's function that is supposed to add said file into my DB.

Here's the code for the view (application/views/pageTEST.php):

```
<HTML>
  <form method = "post">

    <label for = "zone">Zone</label>
    choose zone : <input type = "file" id = "fA" name = "zone" accept = "file_extension/.txt">

    <input type = "submit" id = "btn" name = "loader">

  </form>
<HTML>
```

The code for the controller (application/controllers/modelController.php) :

```
class modelController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('loader');
        $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('pageTEST');
    }

    public function load()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('zone', 'Zone', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == = FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('error');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->loader->loadZone($this->input->post('zone'));
            //this is supposed to load the .txt file i chose in the form and add it into the DB
        }
    }
}
```

I don't need to show the code for my model because it isn't the problem. What I need to know is how to call `modelController->load()` once I click on the submit button.

So far I haven't been able to link them. I tried replacing the code from the `load()` method in the controller with a simple link to some test page, but my view can't reach the function. What am I missing in my code?

Comment: Files go in the $_FILES array not the post array so zone will always be null if you access it via post e.g. $_POST array. And your form needs to be multipart for files and the action should declare the url to the load page.

Comment: I also fail to see how your model isn't relevant. But I guess somehow you tested it with a null variable -__-

Comment: You are naming your controller file and class wrong explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Note: You *can* have angle brackets in your code if you format it as such, by prefixing each line with four spaces. E.g. by using the `{}` code formatting tool.

Answer (score 0):

Your form should be declared like so:

`<form action="<?php echo site_url('modelController/load'); ?> enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Then you can access the file `zone` through the files array:

`$_FILES['zone']`

You may be able to access it via `$_FILES["zone"]["tmp_name"]` (`$this->loader->loadZone($_FILES["zone"]["tmp_name"]);` may work), if not you need to move the file to readable location:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

You can also use CI's upload library for that.

Comment: I've spoken too soon... I thought it worked and hastily replied that it worked but I was misled. When I click on submit  I get a Page not found error(Sorry we can not reach that page) with this link... http://[::1] It's like my application cant find my controller's load function.

Comment: Have you set your apps base url in config? Can you access the load function by going to localhost/modelController/load?

Comment: my routes are like so:  $route['default_controller'] = 'modelController';
$route['modelController/load'] = 'modelController/load';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: and no even if I add modelController/load in the search bar the page is not found.Im gonna try to find a way to make it work. If you find what im missing im very grateful

Comment: Chances are you need to rename your controller. Call it `class Loadzone extends CI_Controller` and name the file `Loadzone.php` and then see if you can access it via `localhost/loadzone/load`

Comment: ^ oh and those routes are not required so remove them, but leave the default controller and set it to the name of the new controller e.g. loadzone

Comment: I changed my controller's name to loadZone, including the name of the php file, I removed all routes except the default controlelr pointing to loadZone.php, and I modified my base_url to :http://localhost:8080. Now I modified my load function in the controller to this single line:$this->load->view('view_test'); In theory it should load this test page I have in the views directory once i click on submit. However it redirects me back to the Uwamp default index page.

Comment: Im starting to run out of ideas and just put my model's code in my view so that it will work for once, but it would totally render the whole MVC architecture useles... I really dont know what to do about it... but thanks for the help

Comment: Again please name it as I have it in the previous recommendation  so not loadZone

Comment: It is imperative that the controller be uppercased first and then all lower.

Comment: I renamed it to LoadZone. Same result. here's the url when I load the default page:http://localhost:8080/BD3_TP1(CI)/ and the url once I click on submit:http://localhost:8080/index.php/LoadZone/load%20%20enctype= and it redirects me back to the uwamp default page, even though I specifically inserted that line in the controller's load function:$this->load->view('view_test'); that should redirect me to this test page, but for some reason it goes back to uwamp. My base url:http://localhost:8080

Comment: what is this `BD3_TP1(CI)`?

Comment: the name of my project. I renamed it from the original name which is CodeIgniter3.0 something.localhost:8080/BD3_TP1(CI) is the main view where I choose my file and submit it.

Comment: so your app is in an htdocs sub directory called `BD3_TP1(CI)`? then your base_url should be `localhost/BD3_TP1(CI)` ... the parenthesis is rather strange - not sure if its affecting anything but weird nonetheless

Comment: and again, please refer to this: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming and *just* call it `Loadzone` not `LoadZone` not `loadZone`... sorry i couldn't be of more assistance.

Comment: The project is in the www folder of Uwamp:C:\Users\User\Desktop\UwAmp\www\BD3_TP1(CI) and I renamed the controller to Loadzone too and i have the same result. Didnt know the name was that important but it hasnt changed anything in this context anyway. Thanks for the support, I'm just gonna have to code everything in the view. i cant stay stuck in this when I have so much more to do. Thanks again for your time